# My Sony A6000 Will not do HSS with interfit sony ttl trigger on honeybadger unleashed

Tags: sony, sony-alpha, high-speed-sync

Out of desperation posting here.  I have a Sony a6000, and an interfit TTL remote for Sony to use with my honeybadger unleashed.   If I click the sync mode button on the remote to HSS, after about 1/2 it reverts back to first sync.   It is like it doesn't know it can do HSS.  I did update the remote, the honeybadger and even the sony a6000 to latest firmware.  I am not sure what else I am doing wrong or if this just does not work.  The camera does see the remote when it is installed and I think can fire the honeybadger on manual and standard modes.

Comment: The [manual for the TTL Remote](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0266/4038/4058/files/instruction-manual-hbu250.pdf?v=1597784935#page=8) says: "Sony users must set their
camera flash mode to “Wireless Flash” for the remote to communicate properly with the camera." What's the flash mode set to on your α6000?

Comment: It is indeed in wireless mode, and that option only becomes available when the remote is plugged in.  So I know it is 'seeing' the remote to at least that point